# Insert `access_token` into all API calls with fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

I'm working on a React app and I'm having trouble finding a "clean" way to automatically authenticate API calls by putting an `access_token` parameter into each query the app sends. The access token is stored in the redux `store`.

I've created a lib file that handles all the API calls:

```
const api_server = 'http://site.dev/'
const api_url = api_server + '/app/api'
const api_version = 'v1'
const client_id = '1_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
const client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

module.exports = {

  getRealtimeFeed: function(page, access_token=''){
    const endpoint = api_url + '/' + api_version + '/posts?'
      + 'limit=6'
      + '&page=' + page
      + '&access_token=' + access_token
    return fetch(
      endpoint,
      { method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }}
    )
  },
}
```

I find it easy to use across the app, except that, as you can see, I always need to pass the access token to the api function.

I then use that api in my `actionCreators.js` file

```
import SiteAPI from '../lib/site.api'

export function fetchLatestPosts(page, accessToken='') {
  return dispatch => {
    SiteAPI.getRealtimeFeed(page, accessToken)
    .then( (response) => {
      if (response.status === 200){
        response.json().then( (json) => {
          dispatch(fetchedLatestsPosts(json.results))
        })
      } else {
        console.error(response)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And in my react `Component`, I call the action function with the access token, but that means all my components need the access token to be passed as a prop.

I'd like to know if there's be a way to set the access token once and for all for the api to use it, instead of having to pass it around every time I make an API call.
I'm fairly new with react & redux so there might be a concept I didn't learn properly yet that would allow me to do such thing, I guess.

Thanks :)

Comment: 1 way is to store the token in a variable under the siteapi file. Export a setter function for it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `redux` store in your API file and use it to retrieve `access_token`:

```
import store from './path/to/your/store'

const api_server = 'http://site.dev/'
...

function getAccessToken() {
  return store.getState().access_token // adjust according to your store structure
}

module.exports = {
  getRealtimeFeed: function(page){
    const endpoint = api_url + '/' + api_version + '/posts?'
      + 'limit=6'
      + '&page=' + page
      + '&access_token=' + getAccessToken()
    return fetch(
      endpoint,
      { method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json" }}
    )
  },
}
```

### EDIT

If you are using [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) then you can get `access_token` in your action (you can define second argument `getState` in `redux-thunk` action function):

```
import SiteAPI from '../lib/site.api'

export function fetchLatestPosts(page) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const accessToken = getState().accessToken
    SiteAPI.getRealtimeFeed(page, accessToken)
    .then( (response) => {
      if (response.status === 200){
        response.json().then( (json) => {
          dispatch(fetchedLatestsPosts(json.results))
        })
      } else {
        console.error(response)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I think this is better decision, because your API methods shouldn't contain `redux` store logic. They should bother API requests only.

Comment: The second solution is perfect. It keeps my API methods separate from React/Redux logic which I definitely like. I'm using that now and it's working fine. Thanks!